# how we compute partial derivative for w respect to x?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If we have
$$
f(x,y) = \arctan\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big),
$$
how we compute partial derivative for w respect to x, that is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Thank you!

Comment: big hint: use the chain rule

Comment: Welcome! This may be of some help: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\arctan{\Big(\frac{y}{x}\Big)}\Big),
$$
that is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -\frac{y}{x^2}\frac{1}{1+\big(\frac{y}{x}\big)^2}
$$